# Visual Studio 2012 Premium crashes when I use the Solution Configuration Manager

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, configurationmanager

Visual Studio 2012 Premium crashes when I use the Solution Configuration Manager (or drop down on tool bar) to switch from Debug solution config to Release. As soon as I make the selection to the Release config, I get a dialog with a progress bar stating it is looking for a solution to the problem and after a few seconds that dialog closes VS closes and another dialog opens that states it is restarting Visual Studio. I get this same behavior if I try to create a new configuration from within the Solution Configuration Manager; i.e., as soon as I save the new config VS crashes. During the crash I'm not given the option in the dialogs to get detailed info for the crash.

This did not happen with the same code in VS2010 and Win7.

My work-around is to modify the Debug config to be what I need for Release, and then put it back to what I need for Debug.

VS 2012 was installed on a clean (not an update) install of Windows 8. I've installed all the latest updates for both Win8 and VS.  Here is the Visual Studio boiler-plate info:

Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012

Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL

Microsoft .NET Framework

Version 4.5.50709

Installed Version: Premium

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012, Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012, Visual Basic 2012, Visual C# 2012, Visual C++ 2012, Visual F# 2012, Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker, NuGet Package Manager   2.0.30717.9005, PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.0, SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.20627.00, Web Developer Tools   1.0.30710.0

Comment: Can you please file a connect bug on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio?

Comment: Got it. Can you attach repro code/project? Thanks.

Comment: I attached the data. I also recorded the crash, but the feedback tool had a problem sending the dump to MS.